# Sending web storage stored JWT to server when refresh button hit

Tags: javascript, jwt

I am building a web app using Javascript (Koa.js as a backend). I do not want to make any full page refreshes, all requests will be ajax requests to my API. I am using *JWT* for user authentication and want to save it in *Web Storage*. These are something, [blog post 1](http://sitr.us/2011/08/26/cookies-are-bad-for-you.html) and [blog post 2](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/#xss-xsrf), I have read on security against especially CSRF, so I need to use *Web Storage* for token keeping on client. I know localStorage persists even across browser quit-relaunches.

The question is;

Are there a, probably convenient to implement and secure, way to achieve keeping an already authenticated user authenticated between page refreshes caused by a non-programmatic way when using *JWT* and *Web Storage*, e.g. browser button hit?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little broad, so there are several answers depending on more information about what you're developing in (what language, any limitations)

I can recommend a few reads to start and possibly shape your question further. First, an article going over the basics of handling JWT tokens:

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/

Another good place to start is looking at Auth0's implementation examples: even if you don't plan on using Auth0's services, the implementations on the server side can be used for plain JWT implementations. Their single-page examples, which include server tutorials, can be found here:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/

Hope this helps!